# WMS Layer as variable on CQL filter?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I've been using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/HYcLt/) CQL filter example, successfully.
However, i wanted to develop it further and the first goal is to allow the user to choose which layer to filter. For that I've added another field on the html form where all the available layers are listed. 
Now the question: How to use that string as a variable on the CQL filter function?
My code looks like this:

```javascript
function updateFilter() {
        var cql = document.getElementById("cql");

        // use a CQL parser for easy filter Validation
        var format = new OpenLayers.Format.CQL();

        //if filter exists, remove it
        //This will also be useful when empty filter is present
        if(Layer_to_Query.params.CQL_FILTER){
            delete Layer_to_Query.params.CQL_FILTER;
        }

        var filter;
        try {
            filter = format.read(cql.value); //we are just checking if we can parse it
        } catch (err) {
            if(cql.value!=""){ //no need to give alert when filter is empty
                alert("Filter cannot  parsed");
            }               
        }
        if (filter) {
            Layer_to_Query.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER':cql.value}) //add the cql filter to the Layer
        }
//redraw the layer
        Layer_to_Query.redraw({force:true});
        return  false;
    }
```

So, any ideas on how to pass the form layer name as Layer_to_Query on the function?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated as I can't see how you have set up your map and added the layer names to your form ect. Basically you are going to have to return the layer object from the list in your map. You could recursively search through the layers until you find one that matches the Name you have in the field. As I don't know how you are displaying or what libraries you are using I can't be any more specific or let you know of any better ways.

Either way this is going to take a little bit of coding and isn't going to be a simple couple of lines of code answer.